# Append to array in async for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous

I've got this function which contains other nested async functions.

I'm unzipping a zipfile and then appending each `HTMLImageElement` to an array.

However, the array is printing like this

[image: console print]

16 is the correct number of images I'm expecting, but they're undefined when I `console.log()` them.

```
export async function fetchVisuals(TestID: number) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    const res = await fetch('*DJANGO URL*', {
        body: JSON.stringify(TestID),
        method: 'POST'
    })
    let http_ok = res.ok
    const blob = await res.blob()
    var bufferPromise = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    zip.loadAsync(bufferPromise).then(async ({files}) => {
        const mediaFiles = Object.entries(files).filter(([fileName]) =>
            fileName.endsWith('.jpg'),
        );
        if (!mediaFiles.length) {
            throw new Error('No media files found in archive');
        }
        // I'm very confident the issue is to do with the below function
        let promiseArray = mediaFiles.map(function([,image]) {
            image.async('blob').then((blob: Blob | MediaSource) => {
                console.log("mediaFiles loop")
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                console.log(img)
                return img
            })
        })
        Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(resultsArray) {
            console.log(resultsArray)
        })
    })
}
```

I'm mapping the promise of each image to an array then doing `Promise.all()` on this array, so I'm not sure why it's still coming back as `undefined`.

Inside of `mediaFiles.map()` I do some prints and they print the img data successfully.

[image: Image prints]

How can I fill this array with the `HTMLImageElements`?

Comment: You forgot to `return image.async('blob')`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yeah that was it. I just read it again after a break and realised i was returning inside `image.async` and that was it... ur change fixed it :)

Comment: Btw use `const {files} = await zip.loadAsync(bufferPromise);` instead of `.then(…)`, same for the other `then` calls. Also you forgot to `return` (or `await`) the `Promise.all(promiseArray)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return your promise in the map function:

```js
        let promiseArray = mediaFiles.map(function([,image]) {
            image.async('blob').then((blob: Blob | MediaSource) => {
                console.log("mediaFiles loop")
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                console.log(img)
                return img
            })
        })
```

Must become :

```js
 // I'm very confident the issue is to do with the below function
        let promiseArray = mediaFiles.map(function([,image]) {
            /*just there : */ return image.async('blob').then((blob: Blob | MediaSource) => {
                console.log("mediaFiles loop")
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
                console.log(img)
                return img
            })
        })
```

For your second question, you must await your promises and return their results :

```js
export async function fetchVisuals(TestID: number) {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    const res = await fetch('*DJANGO URL*', {
        body: JSON.stringify(TestID),
        method: 'POST'
    })
    let http_ok = res.ok
    const blob = await res.blob()
    var bufferPromise = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const {files} = await zip.loadASync(bufferPromise);
    const mediaFiles = Object.entries(files).filter(([fileName]) =>
        fileName.endsWith('.jpg'),
    );
    if (!mediaFiles.length) {
        throw new Error('No media files found in archive');
    }
    // I'm very confident the issue is to do with the below function
    let promiseArray = mediaFiles.map(function([,image]) {
        return image.async('blob').then((blob: Blob | MediaSource) => {
            console.log("mediaFiles loop")
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            console.log(img)
            return img
        })
    })
    return await Promise.all(promiseArray);
}
```

Comment: @Emial Zuubier suggested this as well and it's fixed it :) many thanks

Comment: I must be writing my answer while he posted his comment ^^ Glad it helped you !

Comment: Any ideas how I can return `resultsArray` when `fetchVisuals` is called?

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be ok.